# AngularJS and QUnit: Unknown provider: LocalDataProvider <- LocalData <- FileLogger

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, qunit

Anyone who can help me fix this? I'm such a beginner in unit testing scripts.

Here's my html code.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset = "utf-8">
      <title>QUnit and AngularJS</title>
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.22.0.css">
  <script src = "https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.js"></script>
  <script src = "https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular-mocks.js"></script>
  <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.22.0.js"></script>
  <script src = "OfflineStorage/local-storage.service.js"></script>
  <script src = "AppLogging/file-logger.service.js"></script>
  <script src = "basic.js"></script>
  <script src = "qunit.js"></script>
   </head>

  <body>
      <div id = "qunit"></div>
      <div id = "qunit-fixture"></div> 
   </body>
</html>
```

here's qunit js.

```
var injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'FileLoggerManager']);

module("File Logger Test", function () {
    var svc = injector.get('FileLogger');
});
```

and here's the one that needed to be tested.

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
    .module('FileLoggerManager', [])
    .service('FileLogger', Body);

    function Body(LocalData, $q, $timeout) {
        var service = {
            writeLog: writeLog,
            SetLogLevel: SetLogLevel,
            SetFilePath: SetFilePath,
            SetMaxLogSize: SetMaxLogSize,
            DeleteLogFiles: DeleteLogFiles,
            SendLogsToEmail: SendLogsToEmail
        };

        // LOG WRITER
        var logOb;
        var logDirOb;
        var logLocation;
        var curlogsize = 0;
        var logStrings = [];
        var loggingStopped = true;

        //  DEFAULT CURRENT LOG FILE NAME
        var logfilename = "MPC";
        var appObj = null;
        var maxlogsize = 1000000;
        var customlogfolder = "sdcard/";
        var maxloglevel = 2;

        console.log("File Logger initialized.");

        // SETTINGS
        if (LocalData.loadData('application')) {
            appObj = JSON.parse(LocalData.loadData('application'));

            // MAX LOGFILE SIZE (BYTES)
            maxlogsize = 1000000 * ( appObj.maxLogFileSize ? appObj.maxLogFileSize : 1 );

        //  LOG SAVE PATH CUSTOM FOLDER NAME
            customlogfolder = appObj.logFilePath ? appObj.logFilePath + '/' : 'sdcard/';

            //  MAX LOG LEVEL (everything below will be logged)
            maxloglevel = appObj.logLevel ? appObj.logLevel : 2;
        }

        // DEVICE READY
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

        function onDeviceReady(){
            //  WRITE AND GET LOG FILE READY
            SetFilePath(customlogfolder);
        }

        // SET LOG LEVEL
        function SetLogLevel(logLevel) {
            console.log("File Logger: Set log level to " + logLevel);
            maxloglevel = logLevel;
        }

        // SET FILE PATH
        function SetFilePath(filePath) {
            while (filePath.indexOf('//') > -1) {
                filePath = filePath.replace('//','/');
            }

            while(filePath[0] == '/') {
                filePath = filePath.substring(1);
            }

            if (filePath[filePath.length-1] != '/') {
                filePath = filePath + '/';
            }

            if (filePath.indexOf('sdcard') == 0) {
                filePath = filePath.substring(7);
            }

            customlogfolder = filePath;
            logLocation = cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + customlogfolder;
            console.log("File Logger: Log Path = " + customlogfolder);

            if (customlogfolder == "") {
                initializeLogFile(logLocation);
            } 
            else {
                checkIfDirectoryExist(customlogfolder, cordova.file.externalRootDirectory);
            }
        }

        /*
            CHECK IF DIRECTORY EXISTS
        */
        function checkIfDirectoryExist(filePath, rootDirLoc) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filePath, function(dir) {
                    console.log("File Logger: Path found = " + filePath);
                },
                function (dir) {
                    var curFolder = filePath;
                    var withSubDir = false;

                    if ((filePath.indexOf('/') > 0) && 
                        (filePath.indexOf('/') != filePath.length-1)) {
                        withSubDir = true;
                        curFolder = filePath.substring(0, filePath.indexOf('/'));
                    }

                    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(rootDirLoc, function(dir) {
                        dir.getDirectory(curFolder, { create: true }, function (dirEntry) {
                            console.log("File Logger: New Directory = " + curFolder );
                            if(withSubDir == false) {
                                initializeLogFile(logLocation);
                            }
                        },
                        function(dirEntry) {
                            console.log("File Logger: Create Dir failed = " + curFolder);
                        });
                    },
                    function(dir){
                        console.log("File Logger: Root directory not found = " + rootDirLoc);
                    });

                    if (withSubDir) {
                        filePath = filePath.substring(filePath.indexOf('/')+1);
                        checkIfDirectoryExist(filePath, rootDirLoc + curFolder + '/');
                    }
            });
        }

        // INITIALIZE AND CREATE LOG FILE
        function initializeLogFile(logLocation) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(logLocation, function(dir) {
                logDirOb = dir;
                dir.getFile(logfilename + ".txt", { create:true }, function(file) {         
                    logOb = file;
                    writeToLog();
                });
            });
        }

        // SET MAX SIZE
        function SetMaxLogSize (maxSize) {
            maxlogsize = 1000000 * ( maxSize? maxSize : 1 );
            console.log("File Logger: Max File size = " + maxlogsize);
        }

        // WRITE LOG
        function writeToLog() {
            if(!logOb){
                console.log("File Logger: No log added.");
                return; 
            }

            if(logStrings.length == 0) {
                return;
            }

            loggingStopped = false;
            logOb.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {
                fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
                    logStrings.splice(0,1);
                    if(logStrings.length == 0) {
                        loggingStopped = true;
                    }
                    else {
                        loggingStopped = false;
                        writeToLog();
                    }
                };

                var log = logStrings[0];
                fileWriter.seek(fileWriter.length); 
                var blob = new Blob([log], {type:'text/plain'});
                fileWriter.write(blob);
            }, ReadLogfail);

            CheckLogSize();
        }

        function writeLog(logLevel, str) {
            if (maxloglevel == 0) return;
            if (maxloglevel>=logLevel && logLevel>0){
                var level;
                if(logLevel == 4)
                    level = "DEBUG";
                else if(logLevel == 3)
                    level = "INFO";
                else if(logLevel == 2)
                    level = "WARNING";
                else if(logLevel == 1)
                    level = "ERROR";

                var log = "[" + GetLogDate() + "] " + level + " : " + str + "\n";
                logStrings.push(log);
                if(loggingStopped){
                    writeToLog();
                }
            }
        }

        // CHECK LOG SIZE
        function CheckLogSize(){
            logOb.file(function(file) {
                curlogsize = file.size;
                if (parseFloat(curlogsize)>parseFloat(maxlogsize)) {
                    DeleteLogFiles();
                    initializeLogFile(logLocation);
                }
            }, ReadLogfail);
        }

        function ReadLogfail(e) {
            console.log("File Logger: FileSystem Error");
            console.dir(e);
        }

        // GET DATE (SERIAL/NORMAL)
        function GetLogDate(){
            //var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October",  "November", "December"];
            var date = new Date();
            var dateYear = date.getFullYear();  
            var dateMonth = LogPad(date.getMonth()+1);
            var dateDay = LogPad(date.getDate());
            var dateHour = LogPad(date.getHours());
            var dateMinute = LogPad(date.getMinutes());
            var dateSeconds = LogPad(date.getSeconds());

            return dateYear + '.' + dateMonth + '.' + dateDay + ' ' + dateHour + ':' + dateMinute + ':' + dateSeconds;
        }

        //  ADD 0 if number is below 9
        function LogPad(n){
            return n<10 ? '0'+n : n;
        }

        // DELETE LOG FILE
        function DeleteLogFiles(){
            if (!logOb) return 0;
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(logLocation, function(dir) {
                logDirOb = dir;
                dir.getFile(logfilename+".txt", {create:true}, function(file) {         
                    file.remove(function() {
                        console.log('File logger: File removed = ' + logfilename + ".txt");
                    });
                });     
            });
        }

        function SendLogsToEmail() {
            cordova.plugins.email.isAvailable( function (isAvailable) {
                if(isAvailable) {
                    cordova.plugins.email.open({
                        to:      '',
                        subject: 'MSCM MPC Logs',
                        body:    '',
                        attachments: [logLocation+'MPC.txt',logLocation+'MPC_COMM.txt']
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("No email account is setup in this device.");
                    var confirmPopup  = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        cssClass: 'custom-popup',
                        template: '<div>{{ "confirm_no_email_setup" | translate }}</div>'
                    });
                };
            });
        }

        return service;
    }})();
```

However while writing QUnit test an error occurs. "Unknown provider: LocalDataProvider <- LocalData <- FileLogger".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you don't have a `LocalData` object in this code, and aren't injecting any other angular modules that could have that object defined, which is why the error occurs.

Comment: The LocalData is in the other file. It's in the other module and it is a factory. How to do?

Comment: inject it into your module that is using it:  `.module('FileLoggerManager', ['ModuleWithLocalData'])`.  please note this *isn't* an issue of the testing framework;  this code would not run correctly on a webpage either.

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm sorry but I didn't get it very well. As you can see, in the file logger file the LocalData is in the Body function. Is it wrong? I'm new to this testing framework so that's why I got so many questions.